# how to restrict user to delete two spaces in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, space, keycode

I am creating TAG functionality in my application. So i am using `SpannableStringBuilder` and it's working fine now.
What actually i am doing after every tag i am inserting two spaces. and then i am starting second tag to type after creating tag again two spaces.  Means between every two tags i have two spaces.

**What I am facing**

User can delete this two spaces and then my tag structure collapse. So i want to restrict user to delete this two spaces. User can not enter more than two spaces or can not delete two spaces.

I know we can do this using following but not getting how can i do this?

```
txtDishTags.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
 }
 });
```

I don't understand how to restrict user to delete/enter two spaces.
Please give me any reference or hint.

Comment: If user can enter two space then he can delete too. Normal behavior when you delete space between two tags, they will concatenated and treated as single tag.

Comment: is "txtDishTags" an object of edittext?

Comment: I would rethink the design about the tags. If the user has control over your seperators you use to indicate tags, it's hard to find a logic which is fine for every user input.

Comment: Are you setting tag from input of edittext?